# How do I render the path array key in Drupal 7 where field type = node reference

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I have a node reference field which I can output using `echo render( $content['field_link'] );`

This is fine for one situation in the node but I also need to output just the path of that node. I can output it using `echo $node->field_link['und'][0]['node']->uri['path']` but I don't want to hard code the 'und' and '0' array keys in. There is presumably a way to do it with `render()`.

If someone could point me in the right direction that'd be great, thanks.

Ben

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it with `render` but you don't need to hard code the language code, you can get it from the global variables:

```
global $language;
echo $node->field_link[$language->language][0]['node']->uri['path']
```

You won't be able to get around using the `0` key though, all fields are stored with the potential to be multiple so you will always need to 'pick' which element you want to get.

If the cardinality of your field is 1, you can always assume that the element you're looking is for is at `field_link[$language->language][0]`. If not you'd need to run through each element in the `und` array and decide which one to display.

EDIT

You can also use the `LANGUAGE_NONE` constant (which will generally return 'und', but either way wil be the correct language code for the default content).

Comment: The $language->language variable gives me 'en' but the content is 'und' and there's no 'en' array key in the $node object. Any ideas?

Comment: 'und' is short for 'undefined' and is a synonym of the constant `LANGUAGE_NONE`, so personally I'd use that in place of `$language->language`. Sorry not to have mentioned it before

Comment: So presumably something like `$lang = isset( $node->field_link[$language->language]) ? $language->language : LANGUAGE_NONE;` and using $lang as the array key would be sufficient to cover changes in language settings for the user/node?

Comment: I hadn't actually considered doing that before but yeah, that's by far the best way. I'll be stealing that method from now on :-)